# Using 'pass' passwordmanager within fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, password-store

I have a NAS I want to mount on access. I can do this by adding

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/directory /mountpoint smb3 x-systemd.automount,credentials=home/user/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

to my fstab.

I also want to centralize my passwords using `pass` passwordmanager. No problem, I can do:

```
mount -t smb3 //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/directory /mountpoint -o username=user,password=`pass home/localnetwork `
```

If the GPG-key passphrase is not cached yet, it will promt me to enter it, otherwise it will mount the directory immediatly. This is nice.

Now I want to do this using fstab, however:

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/directory /mountpoint smb3 x-systemd.automount,username=user,password=`pass home/localnetwork ` 0 0
```

Does not work.

Any proper (or hacky) idea how to achive the intended behavior?

Edit: I am runnig manjaro with Linux 6.1 kernel.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your operating system.

Comment: fstab options are passed along literally, so it doesn't work that way. You might have to write your own mount helper. (`/bin/mount.mysmb3`, with `mysmb3` filesystem type in fstab, parse/change the command line arguments before running `mount.smb3` with your modified options). I have never tried it myself, so this is just in theory. Good luck...

Comment: Another option would be to provide the password as a file and use the `credentials` option to pass it along. Maybe it could work with a named pipe too. That would allow you to hack a service that only spits out the credentials when conditions are met (the reader is verified to be the mount.smb3 helper). Or maybe I'm just overcomplicating things...